# React framework how to add jquery in dva

Tags: jquery, reactjs, webpack

React-dva, the package of the webpack is also packaged, so that users can not see the webpack configuration. How to join jquery?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

It's "difficult" to use jQuery with react.js. jQuery works by modifying the real DOM while react.js modifies a virtual DOM. Syncing the changes made on the DOM between the two libraries is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

1,Config jQuery in your package.json.You can find the dependency on npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery (this is a fork from jquery) or GitHub

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "jquery": "version_num",
    ...
}
```

2,Import jQuery where you want to use

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

3,Use it

```
const aDomNode = $("#DomNodeId");
```

4,Tips:Do not use jQuery if not necessary when using React.